# How to generate custom wordpress plugin in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am beginner for wordpress and woocommerce, my requirement is to create a custom plug-in just same as **product** plug-in and from preset.
So, I want to know how I can achieve this functionality?

Please find screenshot for same from here:
[image]

Comment: You should provide an example of what you have tried so far and give more specifications so the questions is clear and concrete

Comment: I have product plug-in in my website and i want to generate preset plug-in . Preset plug-in is same as  product plugin with some addition functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a regular WordPress plugin. WordPress has a very good [Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) for creating plugins.

Generally you create plugins by hooking in the system. You can insert functionalities (actions) or change content (filters) with these hooks. WordPress itself and most common plugins like WooCommerce have such hooks to customize whatever you want via Plugins.

Be sure to check out the [Woocommerce Documention](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/) on that topic and also their [Hook Reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html). Maybe it isn't even necessary to create a plugin … customizations via hooks can also be achieved from within your themes functions.php.